# SQLite return SELECT in CSV format

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, how to get a SELECT result in csv format?

In MySQL would be something like...

`SELECT tag_name FROM tags
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

I already tried it in SQLite but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you run queries using  `sqlite` tool, you can type `.mode csv` to display the results in CSV format. I'm not sure it's possible to change the format during the SQL query itself.

Comment: The query is made from PHP.

Comment: Trying sending the command `.mode csv` prior to executing your query. Or maybe just include it at the beginning of the query.